# Differences between gtk and gtk2

Tags: haskell, gtk, gtk3, gtk2, gtk2hs

There seem to be two gtk2hs libraries on Hackage - [gtk](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk) and [gtk3](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3). Looking at the [source](https://github.com/gtk2hs/gtk2hs), they seem to share the same files and have only minor differences. How are these libraries different?

Comment: These bind to gtk2 and gtk3 respectively.

Comment: It is not the Haskell part that is much different. The Haskell library acts as a wrapper to the gtk library. So it calls a different one.

Comment: Seems that in Gtk2Hs, the 2 means "to", not "two" (like in GTK bindings *to* Haskell). The naming is infortunate as it leads to confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, *gtk* binds to GTK+ 2, and *gtk3*, to GTK+ 3. One place where that information shows up is in the [`pkg-config` fields](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#pkg-field-pkgconfig-depends) of their respective .cabal files (cf. [`gtk.cabal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.14.7/src/gtk.cabal) and [`gtk3.cabal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3-0.14.8/src/gtk3.cabal)).